# Using node.js and wget, wait for the download to end

Tags: javascript, node.js, wget

I am using wget to download some images, but sometimes the image does not download entirely (it starts at the top, and then stop abruptly...)
Here is my code :

```
try {
  var img = fs.readFileSync(pathFile);
}
catch (err) {
  // Download image
  console.log('download')
  wget({
    url: reqUrl,
    dest: pathFile,
    timeout : 100000
  }, function (error, response, body) {

    if (error) {
      console.log('--- error:');
      console.log(error);            // error encountered 
    } else {
      console.log('--- headers:');
      console.log(response); // response headers 
      console.log('--- body:');
      //console.log(body);             // content of package 
      var img = fs.readFileSync(pathFile);
```

and so on...

basically, it tries to find the file located at pathFile, and if he does not exist, I download it on my server with wget. But it seems that wget launch the callback before finishing the download...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are possibly responding to some requests but you're using blocking function calls (those with "Sync" in their name). I'm not sure if you realize but that is blocking your entire process for the duration of that operation and will completely ruin any chance for concurrency if you ever need it.

Today you can use `async`/`await` in Node that looks synchronous but doesn't block your code at all. For example using `request-promise` and `mz` modules you can use:

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const fs = require('mz/fs');
```

and now you can use:

```
var img = await fs.readFile(pathFile);
```

which is not blocking but still lets you easily wait for the file to load before the next instruction is run.

Keep in mind that you need to use it inside of a function declared with the `async` keyword, e.g.:

```
(async () => {
  // you can use await here
})();
```

You can get the file with:

```
const contents = await request(reqUrl);
```

and you can write it with:

```
await fs.writeFile(name, data);
```

There's no need to use blocking calls for that.

You can even use `try`/`catch` with that:

```
let img;
try {
  img = await fs.readFile(pathFile);
} catch (e) {
  img = await request(reqUrl);
  await fs.writeFile(pathFile, img);
}
// do something with the file contents in img
```

One could even argue that you could remove the last `await` but you can leave it to wait for potential errors to be raised as exception on the promise rejection.

Comment: So, can I replace every

var img = fs.readFileSync(pathFile);

by 

 (async () => {
        var img = await fs.readFileSync(pathFile);
      })();

or do I need to put my whole function in an async function ?